# How to add text above a chapter heading without vertical shift

Tags: chapters, journal, vertical-spacing

I want to insert some text (author names and author-related information for a journal) at the top of pages beginning a new chapter. While I know of solutions like textpos and different solutions here, I wanted to find a simple way (because of incompatabilities and speed).

Having a look at how `\chapter` is working in different classes, I redefined `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` and inserted a `\parbox` with zero width and height. Apparently this box is not invisible for latex, so it omits 0.34cm of vertical space in book class. In memoir *and* scrbook the chapter headings are on the exactly same height.

How can I change the code to prevent `\chapter` to omit some of the vertical spacing? Is it possibe to find a way to make the text invisible to `\chapter`?

I would love to have a generic solution (so eg. not touching @makechapterhead because that is not used by scrbook) or at least one that that works at least with memoir, scrbook and book/report class.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%\documentclass[oneside]{report}
%\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage[margin=0pt,paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=10cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cauthor[1]{\def\@cauthor{#1}}
\newcommand\ctitle[1]{\def\@ctitle{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \cmaketitle {}
{
  \bgroup
  \if@openright 
    \cleardoublepage
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
  \else 
    \clearpage
    \let\clearpage\relax
  \fi
  \noindent\parbox[t][0pt]{0pt}{\@cauthor}%
  \noindent\parbox[t]\textwidth{%
  \chapter{\@ctitle}\mbox{}}
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal Position\zsavepos{normal}\hrulefill}

\ctitle{My problem\zsavepos{cmaketitle}}
\cauthor{Schmid\footnote{Blacksmith University}\\
         Kovačević\\
         Ferrari\\
         Kowalski}
\cmaketitle

\noindent This heading (made by \verb|\cmaketitle|) is shifted by
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_diff_dim
\dim_sub:Nn \l_diff_dim {\zposy{normal}sp-\zposy{cmaketitle}sp}
\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \dim_use:N \l_diff_dim } { 1cm }cm~
\ExplSyntaxOff
compared to the normal \verb|\chapter|.


\end{document}
```

And if there is a solution without boxes preventing footnotetext to show up, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found a solution. But maybe others can see if there are problems arising from this approach. At least it seems to work together well with book, scrbook, memoir and also some other classes and also with fncychap. The main part (still) are the `\cauthor`, `\title` and `\cmaketitle`-commands. Using a combination of `\makebox(0,0)[lt]` and `\parbox[t]\textwidth` works well. The `\par` is only needed in the scrbook-class.

```
\newcommand\cauthor[1]{\def\@cauthor{#1}}
\newcommand\ctitle[1]{\def\@ctitle{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \cmaketitle {}
{%
  \bgroup%
  \if@openright %
    \cleardoublepage%
  \else %
    \clearpage%
  \fi%
  \noindent\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\@cauthor}}
  \ifscrbook\else\par\fi
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax \let\clearpage\relax%
  \chapter{\@ctitle}
  \egroup
}
```

[image]
So now everything is perfectly aligned.

Complete document with some tested classes and packages. All tested combinations worked.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{margin=0pt,paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=10cm}{geometry}
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
%\documentclass[oneside]{report}
%\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
%\documentclass[oldfontcommands,oneside]{memoir}
%\documentclass{basque-book}
%\documentclass{ycbook}
%\documentclass{octavo}
%\documentclass{willowtreebook}
%\documentclass{elegantbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
%\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifscrbook
\newif\iffncychap
\@ifclassloaded{scrbook}{\scrbooktrue}{\scrbookfalse}
\@ifpackageloaded{fncychap}{\fncychaptrue}{\fncychapfalse}

\newcommand\cauthor[1]{\def\@cauthor{#1}}
\newcommand\ctitle[1]{\def\@ctitle{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand \cmaketitle {}
{%
  \bgroup%
  \if@openright %
    \cleardoublepage%
  \else %
    \clearpage%
  \fi%
  \noindent\makebox(0,0)[lt]{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\@cauthor}}
  \ifscrbook\else\par\fi
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax \let\clearpage\relax%
  \chapter{\@ctitle}
  \egroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Normal chapter\hrulefill}
text after normal chapter\hrulefill

\cauthor{Schmid\footnote{Blacksmith University}\\
         Kovačević\\
         Ferrari}
\ctitle{Ctitle chapter\hrulefill}
\cmaketitle
text after ctitle chapter\hrulefill

\chapter{Normal chapter\hrulefill}
text after normal chapter\hrulefill

\end{document}
```

Is there a solution without the boxes (to get working footnotes)?